# Drawing line with arrow in excel using xssf libraries

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I want to draw a line with arrow head in excel sheet programmatically, I am able to create the line but not an arrow head in that.
Here is my code where I need to change something I want;

```
XSSFSimpleShape shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(a);
shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.LINE);
shape.setLineWidth(1.5);
shape.setLineStyle(3);
```

I tried using `shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.LEFT_ARROW);` `shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.RIGHT_ARROW);` and `shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.UP_ARROW);` too, but that doesn't helped me.

This is what I have:

[image]

This is what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Drawing` support seems to be not very completely in apache POI. So using the underlying objects is needed.

In Excel the arrows are head end or tail end properties of the line.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTShapeProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTLineProperties; 
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTLineEndProperties;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.STLineEndType;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.STLineEndLength;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.STLineEndWidth;

class ShapeArrow {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {

   Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();

   Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

   CreationHelper helper = wb.getCreationHelper();
   Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

   ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
   anchor.setCol1(2);
   anchor.setRow1(2); 
   anchor.setCol2(5);
   anchor.setRow2(5); 

   XSSFSimpleShape shape = ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).createSimpleShape((XSSFClientAnchor)anchor);
   shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.LINE);
   shape.setLineWidth(1.5);
   shape.setLineStyle(3);
   shape.setLineStyleColor(0,0,255);

//apache POI sets first shape Id to 1. It should be 0.
shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().setId(shape.getCTShape().getNvSpPr().getCNvPr().getId()-1);

   CTShapeProperties shapeProperties = shape.getCTShape().getSpPr();
   CTLineProperties lineProperties = shapeProperties.getLn();

   CTLineEndProperties lineEndProperties = org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.main.CTLineEndProperties.Factory.newInstance();
   lineEndProperties.setType(STLineEndType.TRIANGLE);
   lineEndProperties.setLen(STLineEndLength.LG);
   lineEndProperties.setW(STLineEndWidth.LG);

   lineProperties.setHeadEnd(lineEndProperties);

   FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");
   wb.write(fileOut);

  } catch (IOException ioex) {
  }
 }
}
```

In POI there is a `XSSFShape.getCTShape()` method for getting a `CTShape` object. But with this we are lost with the POI documentation. So see http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/spreadsheetDrawing/CTShape.java for a documentation.